# HelloWorld for iOS application in creating IOS gettting started, i have unknown exception in the running time

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios6, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to implement the getting started [helloWorld](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/chapters/RM_YourFirstApp_iOS/Articles/05_ConfiguringView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-TP40012323-CH7-SW3), on XCode 4.6, but I am getting this sigabart. The code is exactly like the apple website. No errors are produced but in runtime I have this:

```
2013-02-11 12:38:42.594 hellooWorld[1794:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',
 reason: '[<ViewController 0x75562d0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: 
this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key greeting.'

*** First throw call stack:

(0x1c91012 0x10cee7e 0x1d19fb1 0xb7ae41 0xafc5f8 0xafc0e7 0xb26b58 0x230019 
0x10e2663 0x1c8c45a 0x22eb1c 0xf37e7 0xf3dc8 0xf3ff8 0xf4232 0x433d5 
0x4376f 0x43905 0x4c917 0x1096c 0x1194b 0x22cb5 0x23beb 0x15698 0x1becdf9
0x1becad0 0x1c06bf5 0x1c06962 0x1c37bb6 0x1c36f44 0x1c36e1b 0x1117a 0x12ffc 
0x267d 0x25a5)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

I did delete the connections and connect the label, textfield and button again to view controller.m but get the same result. I connectted the textfiled to the delegate but received the same result.

Can someone help elucidate what is going on?

Comment: when are you receiving this sigabrt? it seems like you have not implemented the IBAction method.

Comment: 9/10 times this is (for me) an effect of having multiple referencing outlets. I'd double check your storyboard. Right click on the textfield (or whatever you called greeting and remove those outlets)

Comment: just check this link,this may help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key                                            
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625635/view-and-unknown-exception

Answer (score 0):

Check for the linking of objects or methods in your storyboard connections inspector.